# vs2015 Community requires password to logon to account

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I start VS2015 Community Edition I got this dialog. I did not get this dialog before (may be it is the new year's gift!). I have to respond, or else VS closes.
I find it strange and I am not sure if it is some kind of hack to steel my MSN account credentials, specially that it appears while I am logged on to Hotmail.

Have you encountered this? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. Community Edition is telling me my trial has expired. Do I have to pay for Community edition?
   No, Community edition is free to use. We use the same infrastructure that allows you to unlock VS w/ an online subscription to manage the requirement of signing into Community edition so some of our strings overlap cross these scenarios. Trial here means the period you can use the community edition before you must sign in to fully unlock the IDE.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/08/07/visual-studio-2015-faq/#CommunityEditionTrialExpiry

Comment: Thank you. I think that the approach that MS has taken is kind of strange and confusing. If they wanted this information, they could access the cookie that is already available!